# Providing possible parameters of different types in a statically typed language

Tags: c++, oop, parameters

Say, I have `class Action` which stores some `Guy`s and brings them into the action at some time:

```
class Action {
  std::vector<Guy> guys;

  void bring() {
    Guy newcomer = guys.back();
    switch (newcomer.characteristic) {
      // see below
    }
  }

  // ...
};
```

Here's the problem with that `switch`: a guy can have a trait which may need some further explanation or may need none. For example:

```
case loser: // no more information needed to continue
  banish(guy);
  break;
case buddy:
  Guy buddy = newcomer.whose(); // the "explanation" which is needed for this case
  if (is_here(buddy)) {
    newcomer.happiness += 42;
  }
```

How can I sanely store the information which can be needed? Unfortunately, it may have different types (in terms of the programming language) so providing class members for each possible enumerator doesn't seem a well-scaling option and is error-prone due to the ease of making inappropriate calls:

```
enum Characteristic { // isn't "enum class" for brevity of the example
  buddy, gourmet, loser, // etc.
};
class Guy {
 public:
  Characteristic characteristic;

  Guy whose() {
    if (characteristic != buddy) {
      throw std::logic_error("inappropriate call"); // awful!
    }
    return this->buddy;
  }
  Food favorite() { // for "gourmet"
    // same as above?!
  }
  // etc.
};
```

I've thought about inheritance but came up with nothing satisfying. The best idea seems like

```
void Derived_guy::be_brought(Action& action) {
  // modify action in any way
}
```

However, it requires `Guy` to know about `Action` which is a senior abstraction - bad design?

How else can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might replace your enum by a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which can store any information:

```
struct Buddy
{
    Guy whose;
};

struct Loser{};

struct Gourmet
{
    Food favorite;
};

// ...

using Characteristic = std::variant<Buddy, Loser, Gourmet>;

class Guy {
public:
    Characteristic characteristic;
};
```

And finally:

```
struct MyVisitor
{
    Guy& newcomer;

    void operator()(Loser) const { banish(newcomer); }
    void operator()(Buddy& buddy) const
    {
        if (is_here(buddy.whose())) {
            newcomer.happiness += 42;
        }
    }
    // ...
};

void bring() {
    Guy newcomer = guys.back();

    std::visit(MyVisitor{newcomer}, newcomer.characteristic);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a good idea! Why are you using a visitor here rather than a usual switch-case?

Comment: The usual way to dispatch variant is [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), you might see there way to have *"in-place"* visitors.